# Route Optimization & Google Maps asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have multiple locations with lat ,long, Its not ordered so I need to order it as a route planer like image I have attached. Is there is any way to pass my all lat and long and get return with ordered index.
I'm using ASP.Net MVC C#

Answer (score 4):

Route optimization is a huge topic. There are some services you can use with APIs or you can implement your own.

To be able to implement your own, you need route data between those locations. Route data includes distances and maybe durations if you want to consider traffic as well. Also you need an algorithm to decide ordering.

If you don't need custom deciding factors about ordering, I recommend using an API for it.

Comment: I have unordered locations.I need to get order according to route, is there is any google API for this?

Comment: @AshanUdeshitha I don't think google has one but I know yandex has one [link](https://tech.yandex.com/routing/vrp/doc/concepts/about-docpage/#about__work).

Comment: Thank you @Metin for your guide. Finally, I found this -: https://developer.here.com/blog/delivery-made-easy-with-the-here-waypoint-sequence-api